# How to get the recommended slot?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay at the moment I'm currently getting all the first elements with class `slot` which have enough elements after it with the same class with don't also have `.alreadyBooked`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 addPopOverEvery(2, '.slot:not(.alreadyBooked)');
});

function addPopOverEvery(n, selector) {
 $(selector).each(function() {
  var $original = $(this),
  $self = $(this),
  $is_pop = true,
  i = 0;
  if ($original.prev().is(selector)) {
   for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    $self = $self.prev();
    if (!$self.is(selector) || $self.find('.popOver').length) {
     $is_pop = false;
     break;
    }
   }
  }
  if ($is_pop) {
   $self = $original;
   for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    $self = $self.next();
    if (!$self.is(selector)) {
     $is_pop = false;
     break;
    }
   }
  }
  if ($is_pop) {
   $original.append("<div class='popOver'>This slot would be recommended</div>");
            $original.css("color", "green");
  }
 });
}
```

```css
.popOver{
   width:400px;
   height: 30px;
   background: green;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 999;
   margin-left: 120px;
   opacity: 0.5;
   color: white!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="slot">15:10 18/08/2016</li>
  <li class="slot">15:15 18/08/2016</li>
  <li class="slot alreadyBooked">15:20 18/08/2016</li>
  <li class="slot alreadyBooked">15:25 18/08/2016</li>
  <li class="slot">15:30 18/08/2016</li>
  <li class="slot">15:35 18/08/2016</li>
</ul>
```

Now I want to be able to do the same but having it pick the recommended slot based on the slot time.

E.g.

```
<ul>
  <li class="slot">15:10 18/08/2016</li> <---- So this would be recommended 
  <li class="slot">15:15 18/08/2016</li>
  <li class="slot alreadyBooked">15:20 18/08/2016</li>
  <li class="slot alreadyBooked">15:25 18/08/2016</li>
  <li class="slot">15:30 18/08/2016</li> <--- This would be accepted but not recommended because the slot time isn't the earliest
  <li class="slot">15:35 18/08/2016</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: add a class to those elements based on time using javascript

Comment: @madalinivascu could this be done another way instead of using a class based on time using javascript?

Comment: some regex or conversions will do the same but will require some complex code

Comment: @madalinivascu If I was to use the class name method, how would I go about that? would you be able to provide an example with my code above?

Comment: you will use your server side code to append the class